# Access property in stdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

```
stdClass Object
(
[ModuleAccountInfo] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ServerName] => EAST
                [HostingModule] => ActiveDirectory
                [ActiveDirectorySiteName] => EAST
                [AccountIdentity] => OU=ndla,OU=Hosting,DC=east,DC=domain,DC=local
                [Groups] => 2
                [Users] => 15
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ServerName] => EAST.net
                [HostingModule] => hange
                [DiskQuota] => 375000
                [DiskQuotaAdditional] => 0
                [DateQuotaExceeded] => 0001-01-01T00:00:00
                [DiskSpace] => 58567
                [MailboxesDiskSpace] => 59973051
                [PublicFoldersDiskSpace] => 0
                [MessageArchivingDiskSpace] => 0
                [Contacts] => 8
                [Mailboxes] => 15
```

How do I access the ServerName properties?
This object is held in a $modules variables. The above is the print_r of $modules.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because the `ModuleAccountInfo` property is an array, you'll either need to use a specific index

```
echo $modules->ModuleAccountInfo[0]->ServerName;
```

or loop

```
foreach ($modules->ModuleAccountInfo as $moduleAccountInfo) {
    echo $moduleAccountInfo->ServerName;
}
```

Comment: its more good if you convert it into array from stdClass Object, then you can fetch any member very easily

    $value = get_object_vars($decodedvalues);
    $val =  $value['ModuleAccountInfo']['0']['ServerName'];

Comment: To me, it does not seem that  $value['ModuleAccountInfo']['0']['ServerName'] is simpler than $moduleAccountInfo->ServerName